# How to reinstall my genuine Windows 7 in a new hard drive (SSD)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, installation, ssd, upgrade

I want to update, my laptop to a SSD flash drive, and want to install the windows that came pre-installed in my machine.

I know there is supposed to be a partition on my current hard drive, that has the copy of the windows in, but what if I want to install a fresh installation, on my new flash drive.

I don't want to copy an identical copy from the hard drive to the flash, I want a fresh installation.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see this post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft), you find all URL's available to find the matching Windows version that you need.

You can install this version and use your own (genuine) product key.

Comment: Yes I found those link already, and they are the right links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a disk image copy program like acronis to make a image of your full disk (not the partition). Then extract this image to your new SSD. If you want to fresh install of windows, you can go to the pre-installed partition and make a fresh windows from the pre-installed.

This is just a idea, hope it's help.

Normally I don't like to use pre-installed OS on the Windows's Machines because they install to much bulk software like trail anti-virus and some extra toolbars which annoying and slow down the computer. I suggest to install a fresh new Windows from ISO file from Windows Store, of course you can the original copy download from some pirated site and put your genuine serial.